# Exporting Kriged Values from R

Tags: r, kriging

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to export the values from your kriged data in R. I have them exported as a raster, but I need the actual cell values. The data that I'm working with are fish densities. I'm kriging the data and then converting to densities to abundance. BUT in order to convert to abundances I need the kriged values in .csv format.

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)
library(raster)
library(automap)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)

fsite.fit=fit.variogram(fsite.vario, vgm(model="Sph",psill=fmy.psill,range=fmy.range,nugget=fmy.nugget),
                    fit.method=1)

fXloc = data.frame(Data.krig)$fXloc
fYloc = data.frame(Data.krig)$fYloc
fsite.chull = chull(fXloc,fYloc)
plot(fXloc,fYloc)
lines(fXloc[fsite.chull],fYloc[fsite.chull])

fsite.grid = polygrid(
  xgrid=seq(min(fXloc),max(fXloc),length=100),
  ygrid=seq(min(fYloc),max(fYloc),length=100),
  cbind(
    fXloc[fsite.chull],
    fYloc[fsite.chull]))
names(fsite.grid)=c("fXloc","fYloc")
coordinates(fsite.grid)=c("fXloc","fYloc")
fsite.grid = as(fsite.grid, "SpatialPixels")

plot(fYloc~fXloc,cex=1.2,pch=20,col=2)
points(data.frame(fsite.grid)$fXloc,data.frame(fsite.grid)$fYloc,pch="+")

fsite.ok = krige(fADens~1, Data.krig, fsite.grid, fsite.fit)
```

Now what I want is to export the fsite.ok within fsite.grid but I am unable to join them in the same data frame. I'm not sure where to go from here. Please KINDLY let me know if you would like to me to add anything else. At this time, I am not allowed to share my data.

Comment: There are multiple ways (functions and packages) for working with spatial data in R so you really need to show your code, preferably with a small data set. Have you read the manual page for the kriging function you are using, especially the description of the output the function returns?

Comment: What is the class of objects in your work environment? Or what is the format that you would like to export?, more information is needed to help you.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Yes, see my answer. It is good that you have added the packages used (although you add too many), but  the code is still not reproducible. Do not share your data, just use an example from gstat, as I do below. What is not working for you in my answer?

Comment: the predict function "no applicable method for 'predict'

Comment: That is odd. It should work if you copy and paste the code into a fresh R session. Perhaps after updating packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal, reproducible example from `gstat`. It looks like you are interested in object `fsite.ok`. Presumably a `Spatial*DataFrame`.

Example code

```
library(gstat)
library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
meuse.gstat <- gstat(id = "zinc", formula = zinc ~ 1, data = meuse, 
    nmax = 7, set = list(idp = .5))
meuse.gstat
z <- predict(meuse.gstat, meuse.grid)
```

Now you can do

```
d <- data.frame(z)
write.csv(d, "values.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

So in your example that would be

```
write.csv(data.frame(fsite.ok), "values.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: that worked. I just had to get rid of the row.names=FALSE. Thank you so much!